# Joomla 3 add attribute to article editor

Tags: joomla3.0, custom-fields

I would like to add another custom attribute into the article editor (please check the image below). I would prefer plugin to keep joomla updates working. Some advice? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found an answer. In administration of joomla is possible to clone com_content the same way as in frontend.

Main menu -> Extensions -> Template manager (now choose administrator template) -> Create overrides -> com_content -> Article

Now you can see the path (picture below) and edit what you desire.

[image]